# How to do 8 bit modulo 256 to obtain checksum?

Tags: c, modulo

I'm doing a checksum program and I already have a sample answer but cannot get the proper answer. The program is supposed to calculate a checksum of a file. Here is the way I understand how to calculate the checksum.

File has 11 chars 10 A's and a newline. To my understanding I have to add all the bytes in the array which is 11 bytes. Do 11 % 256, then 256-(11 % 256). That would equal 245.

The answer is supposed to be 294 hex stripped is 94. Where am I going wrong?

Check out this answer
https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

Comment: Add the *values* of the bytes.  For 10 `A`'s and a newline I get 660, modulo 256 is 148.  (Hmm.  That's not the answer you were expecting, either.)

Comment: Looks like you count the bytes instead of adding them. Also "adding" is not necessarily mathmatical adding. Computer people can get as weird as e.g. describing xor operations as adding.

Comment: 0x294 % 256 == 0x94 but 294 % 256 != 94.

Comment: Not sure what "11 chars 10 A's and a newline" means. "AAAAAAAAAA\n"? "abcdefghijAAAAAAAAAA\n" ?

Comment: @SteveSummit ok 10 A's (65 ASCII) is 650 in decimal, new line is 10 so we have a total of 660 % 256= 148. So, 148 is 94 in hex which would be the checksum. How do I display the output 148 to 94 on the C program?

Comment: @Yunnosch Ok 294 is probably wrong. And yes adding interchanged  for xor which wouldn't be proper. You got it AAAAAAAAAA\n

Comment: If you want to display a number in hex instead of decimal, you can printf it using `%x` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 4):

You are not adding up the bytes, you are counting them.

Here is the arithmetic:

```
10 * 65 = 650 // 10 A's

650 + 10 = 660 // + newline

660 % 256 = 148 // mod 256

148 = 0x94 // in hex
```